# My Azure WebApp seems to go idle even with AlwaysOn turned on

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have two an Azure WebApps. Both of them have the "AlwaysOn" option set to true, but even now the WebApps go idle after a bit.

If I don't query the WebApp for a few minutes, the next request I make to the WebApp takes significantly longer. Too long to be acceptable for production.

The WebApp runs a C# ASP.NET MVC 5 project which is my project's API.

Can I do anything to prevent this from keeping on happening?

Comment: i doubt anyone would be able to help you, since you do not provide any logs or any relevant information of any sort. try recreating webapp\try turning alwayson off and on

Comment: Can you provide details about the request? Is this a very simple request with no data calls? or is there more going on?

Comment: @Jonathan any request. Be it data, file upload, anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like having turned off the HTTP to HTTPS rewrite solved the issue. The response is still slow, but much faster than before.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how slow the request is in ms or seconds? Also which service plan level is your web app?

Comment: These are the results of a application I use to test my API's: http://pastebin.com/TF10mecj (this was after a few hours of not querying the API at all). Now it will be fast (~150-300ms per request) until I stop querying it for a few minutes. All pricing tiers are S2.

Comment: Any idea how I can make this faster, Jonathan?

Comment: Can I give any more info maybe to give you a better idea?

Comment: How are you doing your deployment?

Comment: I use the VSTS deployment build server

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm also using HTTP to HTTPS rewrite in web.config. Is that how you handled the rewrite? In our case, it's the initial hit. After that the response time is pretty decent but if the app sits idle for a while, there's a noticeable delay on the first hit.

Comment: Hi Sam. I managed to solve it by disabling the AlwaysOn entirely and running a script remotely (C# tool in my case) which queries the API every X seconds. So basically our own AlwaysOn.